# Slick Slider speeding up after mouse click on image

Tags: javascript, slick.js

When clicking on an image within the Slick Slider all slides are moved forward with high speed. How to get rid of that behaviour?

My JS settings:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.sh_product_slider2').slick({
      slidesToShow: 3,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      arrows: true,
      dots: true,
      centerMode: false,
      variableWidth: true,
      infinite: true,
      focusOnSelect: true,
      cssEase: 'linear',
      touchMove: false,
      prevArrow:'<button class="slick-prev"> < </button>',
      nextArrow:'<button class="slick-next"> > </button>',
               responsive: [                        
                   {
                     breakpoint: 600,
                     settings: {
                       centerMode: false,
                       variableWidth: true,
                       slidesToShow: 1,
                       slidesToScroll: 1,
                       autoplay: true,
                       autoplaySpeed: 2500,
                       pauseOnHover: false, 
                       pauseOnFocus: false,
                       arrows:false
                     }
                   },
               ]
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi! Please add a [Minimal, **Reproducible** Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can 'try' to solve the issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure but seems work according to your sample
just override the css class

```css
.sh_product_slider2 .slick-slide:after {
  position: relative;
}
```

let me know if not works,
thanks